# alternative sql syntax for joined table update

Tags: php, sql, syntax

I need alternative syntax for my sql, to deduct the qty from another table to my raw material table

```
$sql3 = "UPDATE material_inventory 
         join product_check 
         ON material_inventory.qty = material_inventory.qty 
         SET material_inventory.qty = material_inventory.qty - product_check.qty 
         WHERE product_check.pc_id = '$id' 
         AND product_check.date2 = '$date' 
         LIMIT 1";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
```

It looks like limit doesn't work in join update with join clause.
anyway thanks

Comment: `Limit` does work in update with joins. `ON material_inventory.qty = material_inventory.qty` is basically `1=1` which means you have a cartesian product. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: I can also confirm it works. Now, what this tells you is that there's a glaring hole in your logic, and, depending on how you tested whether this works or not, can be a really big one or a rather small one. How did you conclude that it didn't work?

Comment: thanks for reply,what should i do now do you have alternative syntax for that ?  @bassxzero

Comment: which db you are using ???  mysql?

Comment: @scaisEdge the code contains `mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);`.. so.. MySQL?

Comment: @erwin syntax is not the problem, your logic is. Post your full table structure and the expected result.

Comment: what mean limit 1 ?  that you want update just a rows ... ? how you can define which row you need  to updated ?

Comment: well it woks actually,  but i couldn't get my desire result it deducts all rows from my table 'material inventory'. @Mjh

Comment: @erwin That's because the `ON` condition is wrong, as mentioned in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `ON` condition is wrong. Until you add schema of relevant tables, all I can suggest from given scenario is following query:

```
$sql3 = "UPDATE material_inventory 
         join product_check 
         ON material_inventory.qty = product_check.qty        //modified line
         SET material_inventory.qty = material_inventory.qty - product_check.qty 
         WHERE product_check.pc_id = '$id' 
         AND product_check.date2 = '$date' 
         LIMIT 1";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
```

If the above query doesn't get the desired output, please add schema so that I can provide more accurate solution.